# How can I condense these import lines of code?

Tags: python-import

```
from wisconsion1 import *
from alaska1 import *
from texas1 import *
from indiana1 import *
```

Is there some way to simplify this? Esp if I'm going to add more in the future.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can simplify and clean up the code it as follows:

```
import * from wisconsion1, alaska1, texas1, indiana1
```

Comment: When I do this, I get an error when I call my functions (" " is not defined).

Comment: "Unpack operation not allowed in this context"